# how to make my app appear as an option to send a screenshot to?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

after I take a screenshot on my iphone I see various apps I can send the screenshot to for processing (ie evernote or gmail or google keep). I want my app to also appear here as an option. I tried setting the Document Types in Info tab section in xcode with the following:

Name - Note
Types - public.png

Additional document type properties -
Key: LSHandlerRank, Type: String, Value: Alternate

However, my app is not appearing as an option to send the screenshot to. Why is this?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "Share Extension", knowing those keywords, you should easily find lots of online materials on it, e.g. https://hackernoon.com/how-to-build-an-ios-share-extension-in-swift-4a2019935b2e

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. It's amazing that often, all you need to solve a problem, is just to name the problem correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you should build a Share Extension and a request for your screenshot. Here's a good example: https://www.9spl.com/blog/build-share-extension-ios-using-swift/